# SDL2 library fails to initialize

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, glfw

I'm currently working with SDL2 and GLFW3 to create some OpenGL game. Initializing and using GLFW3 is no problem; I'm using GLFW3 for creating the OpenGL context, window, key input etc. and SDL2 for loading images to SDLSurfaces and then converting them to OpenGL textures, but, unlike GLFW3, SDL2 fails to initialize. My initialization code looks like this:

`if (!SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)) return -1;`

It always returns -1 and quits the main function. Does anyone know why this could happen?

Comment: You need to tell us more info, otherwise everbody will try to guess your problem

Comment: You can enumerate your own error codes, to avoid the *return 0 on success* confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The problem

The problem is not with `SDL`. `SDL` actually initializes completely fine. The problem is how you check if the initialization succeeded. Take a look at the [documentation for SDL_Init()](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Init)

> Returns 0 on success or a negative error code on failure; call
>   SDL_GetError() for more information.

In your code code

```
if (!SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)) return -1;
```

In the `if`, the `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)` part will return `0`, which evaluates to `false` but it still means that SDL was successfully initialized. The `!` in front, means the entire `if` will evaluate to true, and `-1` will be returned.

### Solution

A better soltion is to check if it's equal to `0` and if it does fail, used `SDL_GetError()` to print the error.

```
if ( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0 )
{
    std::cout << "Error : " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: @DocCoock Glad to be of any help. Please accept the answer so that other people with the same problem sees it.

Comment: A small side note on using 0 as error code for success: There's only one way things can go right, but many ways things can go wrong. And there is only one 0 (0 is a very special number) but many nonzero values. In my own code I usually use 0 for success, positive integers to indicate nonfatal errors (i.e. errors from which the program can recover) and negative values for fatal errors (i.e. errors which prevent the program from further execution and should result in a controlled process termination).

Comment: @datenwolf I agree, there's only one way it can succeed. Another way is to use an `enum class`. This way, you error code will always have a meaning without having to look up the error code. And you prevent errors like this.

Comment: @olevegard: Enums in C are just numerical values. And no C compiler will complain, except for signedness, about implicitly casting an enum to an integer. Usually most C compilers will complain though, if not all tokens of an enum type are considered in a `switch` without a default label.

Comment: @datenwolf Yeah, it's different for `C`. But how do you know what an error means if it's just a value? And do you have a method for easily printing what the error means?

Comment: @olevegard: Of course you should use enums for error values (I do that all the time). For translating errors code into something meaningful, there is a helper function into which you pass the error code and it returns a pointer to a static scope string constant describing the error (actually two strings, a short and a long version). Essentially it's a large switch statement; the benefit of using a switch instead of a LUT is, that it can failsafe on invalid error codes.